# How to find the equation of a plane given a line in this plane and a distance from a point?

Tags: geometry

So I have a question which goes like this:

Find the equation of a plane containing the line: $$\left\{\begin{align*}x &= 1 + k\\ y &=1\\ z &= -2k\end{align*}\right. ,\quad k\in\Bbb{R}$$ and lying at distance one from the point $(-1,0,1)$.

I wouldn't even know how to start this as I am used to having questions which are usually simpler than this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of proper notation, I do not know how to use this website very well at all, so I apologize for any inconvenience this might cause to anyone who is kind enough to answer my question.

Comment: What kind of an excuse is “ I’m used to simpler questions”?  Indeed , this is probably a new kind of problem for you, once which is undoubtedly covered in your learning material. And if you are just doing random problems without consulting the leaning material and/or teacher, I would say that is the problem you should work on first.  Locate the matter in your text/ notes and go from there.

Comment: You need the formula $d=|ux_0+vy_0+wz_0-h|/\sqrt{u^2+v^2+w^2}$ giving the distance of the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ to the plane with equation $ux+vy+wz=h$. Have you seen it in your lecture notes ?

Comment: There might be more than one solution. Find the lines that are tangent to the sphere of radius 1 around the point.